# How to apply special filters to image using PHP?

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd

I was working on image filters using PHP, but I am unable to find some filters like those at https://pinetools.com/. In particular, the ones listed below:

- [Clip Image](https://pinetools.com/clip-image)
- [Adjust channels](https://pinetools.com/channels-image)
- [Change Image exposure](https://pinetools.com/change-image-exposure)
- [Vibrance](https://pinetools.com/change-image-vibrance)

I couldn't find these filters' solution in PHP GD filters or in PHP Imagick, based upon ImageMagick.

Is there any solution for this. Are there any of these filters there that I could not find?
How do I apply these filters to an image in PHP Imagick?

I know the question is broad please don't devote it, I thought it strange to post a separate question for each filter?

Comment: what have you tried so far ? have you tried googling 'applying image filters in php' ?

Comment: I have tried for each filter separately, some filters worked perfect, some resulted poorly but for these unfortunately I didn't find any hint?

Answer (score 2):

I have worked out the equivalent of Pinetools clip image in ImageMagick commands for values between 0 and 50.

Input:

[image]

For example at 50, clip image produces the following:

[image]

The following ImageMagick command reproduces that:

```
convert lena.jpg -black-threshold 50% -white-threshold 50% clip_image_imagemagick.png
```

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

The functions to use in Imagick are:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.blackthresholdimage.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.whitethresholdimage.php

I do not know Imagick, but looking at the documentation, it appears that it wants a threshold value as a color, so try "gray(50%)" when the clip image value is 50.

Similarly, I have worked out the equivalent of Pinetools Adjust colors.

Here is the result for Pinetools red adjust 50.

[image]

In ImageMagick, that would be:

`convert lena.jpg -channel r -level 0x50% +channel adjust_red_50.png`

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

And the Imagick command is:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.levelimage.php

But I am not sure what the values are. I believe they may be number in the range of 0 to quantum range. So if your IM version is Q16, then 0 to 65535 and if Q8, then 0 to 255. So 50% in Q16 would be 65535/2=32767.5. So

levelImage (0, 1.0, 32767.5, $channel = Imagick::CHANNEL_RED );

For Pinetools exposure 50, I can come close using the ImageMagick command -evaluate add.

Pinetools Exposure 50:

[image]

The ImageMagick command would be:

```
convert lena.jpg -evaluate add 40% lena_add_40%.png
```

[![enter image description here][7]][7]

And for Pinetools Exposure 100:

[image]

And the ImageMagick command would be twice that:

```
convert lena.jpg -evaluate add 80% lena_add_80%.png
```

[![enter image description here][9]][9]

The Imagick command for 50 would likely be:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.evaluateimage.php

```
evaluateImage(Imagick::EVALUATE_ADD, 26214);
```

where 65535*40/100=26214

For Pinetools Vibrance 50:

[image]

You can do that in ImageMagick by changing colorspace to HSL (or HCL or similar), then applying sigmoidal-contrast to the Saturation/Chroma channel.

A close equivalent would be:

```
convert lena.jpg -colorspace HSL -channel g -sigmoidal-contrast 3,0% +channel -colorspace sRGB tmp.jpg
```

[![enter image description here][11]][11]

In Imagick, you would change colorspace using:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.transformimagecolorspace.php

Then apply sigmoidalcontrastImage to the Saturation channel which in HSL would be the green channel:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.sigmoidalcontrastimage.php

Then convert the colorspace back to (s)RGB.

Note that sigmoidal contrast is non-linear. You want to set the mid-point to 0% so that the straight part of the curve is at 0 and the curved part that curves over to near flat is at the top right. So it is like a non-linear brightness control on the Saturation.

Comment: thanks @fmw42 i will try this. please upvote my question

Comment: If my answer was useful, then please consider giving it an up-vote. Sorry, I do not know Imagick that well.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find one-to-one matching of those filters. But you can get similar effects in Imagick (or ImageMagick directly) with the following, though argument control is different.

clip image is https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.contraststretchimage.php

adjust channels is
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.levelimage.php

change exposure is also
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.levelimage.php

There is no vibrance exact equivalence, but you can change saturation using:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.modulateimage.php

If you are on Unix-like systems, you can use PHP exec() and run some of my bash ImageMagick shell scripts. I have several for vibrance and exposure (called xposure) and one for brightness-contrast adjustment. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

Comment: I just found solution of adjust channels, we can accomplish that task with <a href="http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php"> colorize image filter</a>.Still searching for others.

Comment: I am using Windows10

Comment: Please try the referenced Imagick filters and adjust the arguments to get similar functionality. If you cannot achieve a similar result, then post your input image, output images and Imagick code. I could try to reproduce it in Imagemagick, but someone else would have to convert that to Imagick equivalents, since I do not use Imagick.